# If $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ is bounded, does that imply $f(z)$ is bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof that if $f(z)$ is entire and the real part of $f$ is bounded ($Re(f) \leq M$), then $f$ is a constant, the first line of the proof is that we define $g = e^f$, so $\lvert g \rvert = \lvert e^f \rvert = e^{Re(f)} \leq e^M$ and so $g$ is a bounded entire function. I understand the steps, but I don't understand why because $\lvert g \rvert$ is bounded, $g$ is necessarily bounded.

Comment: Doesn't bounded for $g : D \subset \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ mean there exists a real constant $M > 0$ such that $$|g(z)| < M \ \ \text{ for all } z \in D$$

Hence $|g|$ bounded implies $g$ bounded.

Comment: If $|g|$ is bounded (suppose $0 \leq |g| < L$), then isn't $g$ necessarily within the disc of radius $L$?

Comment: Yes. g is bounded because $e^{Re(x)}$ is an increasing monotonic function. Hence, $max e^{Re(x)} = e^{max(Re(x))}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats the definition of a bounded function.

> A function $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$, is bounded if there exists a positive real $M$ such that 
>   $$
> |f(z)| \leq M \ \forall \ z\in G
> $$

In your case, put $M_1=e^M$, since $|g(z)|\leq M_1$ For all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $g$ is bounded.